# Univocity parser issue with empty string field

Tags: java, univocity

For fixed width parsing using multiple lookahead, the empty string causes issues (i.e., `fieldX='    '`). So for fixed format file with only 2 records, if the first record ends with a empty string field, then this causes a issue. The last field in the record is treated as empty(null), and it does not treat the first character in the next record as a lookahead, but instead the second character. If the last field in the first record has a non-empty value (`fieldX='11111'`), then this is not an issue and it works. The workaround for me was to set `settings.getFormat().setPadding('~')` to some character not expected in the file.

Is there any settings to allow to accept empty strings and treat them as '    ' and not NULL.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Author of the library here.

Does `settings().setNullValue("");` help?

If not, can you please updated your post to include a sample of the input and the code you are using to parse it so I can reproduce this and check?

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work, as last field in first record has x number of blank spaces. So if I have a field with 5 spaces, I want it to appear as 5 spaces in record as it is fixed format.

Comment: Also, if last field is treated as NULL, then the look ahead of the next record should begin on first character of second record, but instead it goes to second character.

Comment: @user518066 it looks like you should disable trimming whitespaces. Use: `settings.trimValues(false);` as well and let me know how that goes.

Comment: already tried settings.trimValues(false), but that did not fix.

Comment: Ok can you please update your question to include a sample of the input and the code you are using to parse it so I can reproduce this and check?

Comment: Using the settings.trimValues(false); worked for me, thanks.